# Mockito: Mock a class but set the value of the final field when the constructor is protected

Tags: java, mockito

Here's the class:

```
public class A {

   public final SqlOperator op;
   public final ImmutableList<RexNode> operands;
   public final RelDataType type;

   protected A(RelDataType type,SqlOperator op,List<? extends RexNode> operands) {
     assert type != null : "precondition: type != null";
     assert op != null : "precondition: op != null";
     assert operands != null : "precondition: operands != null";
     this.type = type;
     this.op = op;
     this.operands = ImmutableList.copyOf(operands);
     assert op.getKind() != null : op;
     assert op.validRexOperands(operands.size(), Litmus.THROW) : this;
}
```

I want to mock class A but set the value of "operands" field to an empty list. The field being final I cannot modify it outside the constructor when I mock the class.

I tried to use Reflection but that didn't work with Mockito.

The code for which test case is needed:

```
public static String extractGranularity(A call) {
    if (call.getKind() != SqlKind.FLOOR || call.getOperands().size() != 2) {
        return null;
    }
    final B flag = (B) call.operands.get(1);   // This is the problem area
    final TimeUnitRange timeUnit = (TimeUnitRange) flag.getValue();
    if (timeUnit == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return timeUnitSwitch(timeUnit);
}
```

Comment: Why do you need a mock, can't you use a new here or some spy maybe?

Comment: @RC. For creating a spy, I will have to create an object of A. Since it has a protected constructor, I cannot do that. Secondly how would spy help? I don't want to call any real implementation of the method, just want to set the value of operands field.

Comment: @René Link. I've added the code which I need to test.

Answer (score 0):

OK so here's something based on the classes you did post (I assume the real ones are a little bit different):

```
package so45078998;

import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList;
import java.util.List;

public class A {

    public final SqlOperator op;
    public final ImmutableList<RexNode> operands;
    public final RelDataType type;

    protected A(RelDataType type, SqlOperator op, List<? extends RexNode> operands) {
        assert type != null : "precondition: type != null";
        assert op != null : "precondition: op != null";
        assert operands != null : "precondition: operands != null";
        this.type = type;
        this.op = op;
        this.operands = ImmutableList.copyOf(operands);
        assert op.getKind() != null : op;
        assert op.validRexOperands(operands.size(), Litmus.THROW) : this;
    }

    public Object getKind() {
        return op.getKind();
    }

    public ImmutableList<RexNode> getOperands() {
        return operands;
    }

    static class SqlOperator{

        private Object kind;

        public Object getKind() {
            return kind;
        }

        void setKind(final Object kind) {
            this.kind = kind;
        }

        boolean validRexOperands(int size, Litmus litmus) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    static class RexNode{
        private Object value;

        public Object getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        void setValue(final Object value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }
    static class RelDataType{}
    static enum Litmus{ THROW }
}

// ------------------------------------------------------

package so45078998;

public class ToTest {
    public static String extractGranularity(A call) {
        if (call.getKind() != SqlKind.FLOOR || call.getOperands().size() != 2) {
            return null;
        }
        final B flag = (B) call.operands.get(1);   // This is the problem area
        final TimeUnitRange timeUnit = (TimeUnitRange) flag.getValue();
        if (timeUnit == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return timeUnitSwitch(timeUnit);
    }

    private static String timeUnitSwitch(final TimeUnitRange timeUnit) {
        return "OK";
    }

    enum SqlKind { FLOOR, OTHER }
    static class TimeUnitRange {}
    static class B extends A.RexNode {}
}
```

And the test class (both tests are *green* here):

```
package so45078998;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ToTestTest {
    @Test
    public void testExtractGranularityWithKindNotFloor() throws Exception {
        ToTest.B rexNode1 = new ToTest.B();
        ToTest.B rexNode2 = new ToTest.B();
        List<A.RexNode> operands = new ArrayList<>();
        operands.add(rexNode1);
        operands.add(rexNode2);
        final A.RelDataType relDataType = new A.RelDataType();
        final A.SqlOperator sqlOperator = new A.SqlOperator();
        sqlOperator.setKind(ToTest.SqlKind.OTHER);
        A a = new A(relDataType, sqlOperator, operands);

        Assert.assertNull(ToTest.extractGranularity(a));
    }

    @Test
    public void testExtractGranularity() throws Exception {
        ToTest.B rexNode1 = new ToTest.B();
        ToTest.B rexNode2 = new ToTest.B();
        rexNode2.setValue(new ToTest.TimeUnitRange());
        List<A.RexNode> operands = new ArrayList<>();
        operands.add(rexNode1);
        operands.add(rexNode2);
        final A.RelDataType relDataType = new A.RelDataType();
        final A.SqlOperator sqlOperator = new A.SqlOperator();
        sqlOperator.setKind(ToTest.SqlKind.FLOOR);
        A a = new A(relDataType, sqlOperator, operands);

        Assert.assertEquals("OK", ToTest.extractGranularity(a));
    }
}
```

This works because the test class and the tested class share the same package name (and so you can call directly `new A(...)`).

No if you want to suppress some A behavior, use a spy and use it to control the behavior when required.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try hacking with Unsafe:

```
sun.misc.Unsafe unsafe = null;
try {
  final PrivilegedExceptionAction<sun.misc.Unsafe> action = () -> {
    Field unsafe = sun.misc.Unsafe.class.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe");
    unsafe.setAccessible(true);
    return (sun.misc.Unsafe) unsafe.get(null);
  };
  unsafe = AccessController.doPrivileged(action);
} catch (Exception e) {
  throw new RuntimeException("Unable to load unsafe", e);
}
long operandsOffset = unsafe.objectFieldOffset(
                                A.class.getDeclaredField("operands"));
A instance = // your instance of A
ImmutableList<RexNode> yourOverridingList = ...
unsafe.getAndSetObject(instance, operandsOffset, yourOverridingList);
```

Answer (score -3):

**Encapsulate**, you fool!!!

Encapsulating is hiding the actual implementation details of a class. So in your case right now you use `myA.operands` to access the actual operands. And that could potentially bring some troubles. Instead of having all your attributes public make them `private` and add some accessor methods:

```
public class A {

   private final ImmutableList<RexNode> operands;
   // rest of attributes and constructor...

   public ImmutableList<RexNode> getOperands() {
       return operands;
   }
}
```

Not only you'll be following a good practice but also mocking it will be easier:

```
A myA = mock(A.class);
Mockito.when(myA.getOperands())
    .thenReturn(/* what you want it to return */);
```

Comment: That's a legacy code which I am not allowed to change. Can you suggest a way to deal without changing the code?

Comment: Since the constructor is `protected` you could use it in the same package so you could instantiate a new `A` with mocks. If you're trying to test it from another package (bad practice if it's a unit test) you could write a new class with public constructor (in your test codebase) that extends `A` and in its constructor call `super(...)` with the arguments you need